# Content-length is capped to 2 GB

Tags: php, download, filesize

I've created a script that lets the user download files:

```
function file_size($filename)
{
    exec('stat -c %s ' . escapeshellarg($filename), $return);
    return (float)$return[0];
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . file_size($filename));

readfile($filename);

exit;
```

Very simple. The `file_size` function lets me detect file sizes larger than 2 GB.

**The problem** is that `Content-length` never is above 2 GB:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2011 09:33:20 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Description: File Transfer
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=very-large-file
< Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
< Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: public
< Content-Length: 2147483647
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Doing a var_dump on `'Content-Length: ' . file_size($filename)` returns `string(26) "Content-Length: 4689218232"`. If I access the file directly without a PHP script, there is no problem and Apache is reporting the correct file size:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 21 Aug 2011 09:58:33 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Jan 2011 21:56:47 GMT
< ETag: "8ba8f5e0-1177fcab8-49934940b30e5"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 4689218232
```

But I'd really like to serve the file through my PHP script. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending huge files with `readfile` is not good practice.

Use `X-Sendfile`, like this: `header("X-Sendfile: $filename");`. You'll need apache `mod_sendfile`. This should also solve your file-size problem.

Comment: Thanks thought this was going to work. But X-Sendfile reports that the file is only 375 MB.

Comment: I'm btw running Apache 2.2.17 and X-Sendfile 0.9-2... doh that's my problem. Need to compile latest, since 0.11 adds support for large files.